# How to get spans from a text file on sd card on Android?

Tags: android, string, spannable

i have written a code where i get the number of spans in an Edittext like bold italics or underline.

Now i am getting a text file with something written in it in bold characters and using `BufferedReader` i am getting the contents of that file. Is it possible to get the spans also on that file ?

This is how i get spans from my string in my edittext. Is it possible to get the spans from a text file on sd card ?

```
                    Spannable ss = new SpannableString(text.getText()); // text is an EditText
                    if(text.getSelectionStart() - text.getSelectionEnd() == 0){

                    }
                    else{
                        int prologueStart=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        int epilogueEnd=-1;
                        for (UnderlineSpan span : getUnderlineSpans(ss, text.getSelectionStart(),text.getSelectionEnd())){
                            int spanStart=ss.getSpanStart(span);

                            if (spanStart < text.getSelectionStart()) {
                                prologueStart=Math.min(prologueStart, spanStart);
                            }

                            int spanEnd=ss.getSpanEnd(span);

                            if (spanEnd > text.getSelectionEnd()) {
                                epilogueEnd=Math.max(epilogueEnd, spanEnd);
                            }

                            ss.removeSpan(span);
                        }

                        if (prologueStart < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                            ss.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), prologueStart,
                                    text.getSelectionStart(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        }

                        if (epilogueEnd > -1) {
                            ss.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), text.getSelectionEnd(), epilogueEnd,
                                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        }

                    }
                    text.setText(ss);
                    text.setSelection(cursorPosition);


protected UnderlineSpan[] getUnderlineSpans(Spannable ss, int selectionStart,
        int selectionEnd) {
    return(ss.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, UnderlineSpan.class));
}
```

Comment: Files do not have spans. Text files do not have bold characters. Please explain **completely, precisely, and accurately** what you mean by "a text file with something written in it in bold characters". Do you really mean that you have an HTML file with `<b>` tags?

Comment: I have a .txt file in which i have written my name in bold characters and stored that file in sdcard on Android Device. Now i am accessing the file contents programmatically and setting the contents in an edittext. Now is it possible to retrieve the bold span from the contents of that file ? Because it is possible to retrieve if i have a spannable string declared in my code

Comment: "I have a .txt file in which i have written my name in bold characters and stored that file in sdcard on Android Device" -- text files cannot have "bold characters". Please explain **completely, precisely, and *accurately*** what you mean by "a text file with something written in it in bold characters".

Comment: If you are storing the text in the .txt file without considering markup you won't be able to bring it back. You have to store it using HTML for example, so at the moment to save it you convert each span to the corresponding html tag and when you open it, you make the opposite procedure.